# Difference between two array when elements are array

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var a = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"],["Red","Small"]];

var b = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"]];
```

> So my result will `[["Red","Small"]]`

Not that `a.filter(x => !b.includes(x))` won't work because all element are array.
I've tried something like that

```
    var diff = [];
    a.forEach((res, i) => {
      b.forEach((res2, j) => {
        if (i === j && !_.isEqual(res, res2)) {
          diff.push(res);
        }
      });
    });
console.log(diff);
```

This not working when different elements are last positions

Comment: Will `a` always contain more (or the same) elements as `b`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `O(N)` solution that doesn't require a library, I'd `map` `b` to a `Set` of strings by stringifying the contents of each sub-array, then `filter` `a` by whether `a`'s stringified items are contained in the set:

```js
var a = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"],["Red","Small"]];
var b = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"]];

const bSet = new Set(b.map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr)));
const aFiltered = a.filter(arr => !bSet.has(JSON.stringify(arr)));
console.log(aFiltered);
```

(`Set.has` is generally `O(1)`, unlike Array methods like `includes` and `indexOf`)

Comment: Yes. I like this technique without lodash. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In lodash, you can use [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#differenceWith) and supply [`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) as a comparator to perform a deep comparison:

```
const c = _.differenceWith(a, b, _.isEqual);
```

---

Full snippet:

```js
const a = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"],["Red","Small"]];
const b = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"]];

const c = _.differenceWith(a, b, _.isEqual);

console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are already using lodash you can use combination of filter and every to compare two array.

```js
var a = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"],["Red","Small"]];

var b = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"]];


var unique = a.filter(a=> b.every(b=> !_.isEqual(a, b)));
console.log(unique)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"],["Red","Small"]];

var b = [["Green","Medium"],["Green","Small"],["Medium","Red"]];

var c = b.map(ele=>JSON.stringify(ele));

var p = a.filter(ele=>!c.includes(JSON.stringify(ele)))

console.log(p)
```